# How extract an observable from an observable with a pipe method?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

How can I extract a result of an observable in a pipe method? I have the following:

```
// type of "observables" is Observable<Observable<MyType>[]>
const observables = this.http.get<MyTypeList>(rootUrl).pipe(
  map(list => list[locale]), 
  map(urlList => urlList.map(url => this.http.get<MyType>(url))),
  // I need some method here to make Observable<MyType>[] from Observable<Observable<MyType>[]>
);

forkJoin(observables).subscribe(/* I have all my items here*/)
```

After the second `map` call I need some method to make `Observable<MyType>[]` from `Observable<Observable<MyType>[]>` Is there an elegant way of doing this?

Comment: what if you replace the 2nd map() to mergeMap() ?

Comment: It remove the array not the outer observable: `Observable<Observable<MyType>>`

Comment: add `concatAll()`, `mergeAll()`, `concatMap(a => a)` or `mergeMap(a => a)` after the second `map`.

Comment: It will result in `Observable<MyType>` but I need `Observable<MyType>[]`.

Comment: You want array of Observables?

Comment: I want to get `Observable<MyType>[]` what I can `forkJoin` after

Comment: `flatMap(url => this.http.get<MyType>(url))` ? Flattening is definitely needed here. **2 * map() = stream of streams = not what you usually want**

Comment: BTW, flatMap is an alias for mergeMap - they're the same operation

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I have tried to use the forkJoin outside, I figured I can use it inside with the suggested `mergeMap`.

```
const obs = this.http
  .get<MyTypeList>(rootUrl)
  .pipe(
    map(list => list[locale]), 
    mergeMap(urlList =>
      forkJoin(
        urlList.packages.map(url => this.http.get<MyType>(url))
      )
    )
  );

obs.subscribe(/* I have all my items here*/);
```